# How to solve code conversion issue?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

```
Public Function SaveCommentsTreeComments(ByRef f As System.Windows.Forms.Form) As Integer
    Dim IsNewSubComment As Boolean
    Dim IsNewCommentWithSub As Boolean
    Dim sql As String
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim CommentID As Short
    Dim SubCommentID As Short
    Dim Index As Short
    'WMB 1/28/2004 nextval
    Dim cSql As String
    Dim cRs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cSeq As Double

    On Error GoTo SaveCommentsTreeCommentsError

    SaveCommentsTreeComments = -1

    If Not ValidateCommentsTreeComments(f) Then
        SaveCommentsTreeComments = -2
        Exit Function
    End If


    If f.CommentsText(CommentsTextAbbreviation).Enabled And f.CommentsText(SubCommentsTextDescription).Enabled Then
        IsNewCommentWithSub = False
```

I am getting the error below from the above code while upgrading it from vb6 to vb.net. I don't know which class is missing.

> 'CommentsText' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Form` is the base class from which your actual form(s) inherits.  By passing it `As Form` you are down casting to that base class which does not have any of the controls or methods you've added.  Pass it `As myForm` using the actual class name of the form.

Comment: But passing As myForm .. do i need not to assign something to myForm

Comment: `f` is the actual variable (in your snippet), so that would be the form instance passed.  `As myForm` is the Type allowed to be passed so you cant pass some other form which doesnt have the required properties/methods.  MSDN has a large section on VB6 migration which you might want to consult.  Unlike VB6, you should use form *instances*.

Comment: please post the original VB6 code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change:

```
Public Function SaveCommentsTreeComments(ByRef f As System.Windows.Forms.Form) As Integer
```

To:

```
Public Function SaveCommentsTreeComments(f As YourFormClassName) As Integer
```

This changes two things, first f will now be of the right type and have a `CommentsText` property, field or function.  Secondly, when passing parameters the default for VB6 is ByRef, when VB.NET was developed, they realized this was a mistake and corrected it, but the conversion does not do the analysis necessary to determine if ByRef was required or not. Since it's not necessary in this case, it should be removed or changed to ByVal.